# Applying the assign function over a list/vector of desired variable names

Tags: r

Say I have a vector v1 containing variable names, and I want to assign a value (stored in a seperate vector) to each of these. How can I do this without iteration?

```
v1 <- c("a","b","c")
v2 <- c(1,2,3)
```

What I want to achieve without a loop:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  assign(v1[i],v2[i])
}
```

I feel like I'm close with `purrr:map2` but I've tried different input classes, functions, etc and can't get it to write the variables to memory.

`map2(v1,v2,function(x,y) assign(x,y))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really wanted to put them in the global environment, you can use

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(v2), v1), envir = .GlobalEnv) # no need for assign()
```

but instead I recommend keeping them in a list:

```
vars <- setNames(as.list(v2), v1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular old `Map`:

```
Map(function(x,y) assign(x, y, envir = .GlobalEnv), v1, v2)
```

The key is if you want to use and see these variables outside your function, you need to specify the environment to assign them in. In this case I chose the global environment.

Answer (score 1):

This will assign the variables into the current environment.  Replace `environment()` with whatever environment you want if that is not the environment you want to assign into.  `junk` is not used.

```
junk <- Map(`assign`, v1, v2, MoreArgs = list(envir = environment()))
a;b;c
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
```